# How do i can echo the number of records in php, using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How do i can echo the number of records saved in database. using php and my sql. for example i want to know the number of records uploaded on 28-August-2014..... where table name is product, and date as a field name. . 
only echo the number of records, not to fetch all records.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(1) as recordcount FROM tablename WHERE` etc....

Comment: $today=date(y-m-d);    mysql_query("select * from product where dt='$today'");

Comment: Why don't you go a google research or learn the basics first ?

Comment: See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select count(1) as total from product where date='$date';
```

Answer (score 0):

The mysql_num_rows function will spit out the number of rows returned by a query:

```
echo mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM product WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-08-28' AND '2014-08-28 23:59:59';"));
```

OR

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM product WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-08-28' AND '2014-08-28 23:59:59';"));
echo $row;
```